# Getting Python HttpServer response instantly

Tags: python, flush, httpserver

I am using `Python HttpServer` in the server side. One `GET` request will take more time to respond and I want to update the user the current status of it, such as `'Fetching module X. Please wait'`, `'Fetching module Y. Please wait'`.

But, it is not getting updated in the client side even though I sending it in between the modules. I have tried flushing the stream, but no luck.

```
self.wfile.write('Fetching module X. Please wait')
self.wfile.flush()
```

How can I force the `HttpServer` to send the information instantly, instead of waiting for the completion of full response ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python threading

```
from threading import Thread
t = threading.Thread(target=function to be call, args=[request])
t.setDaemon(False)
t.start()
```

This code will force to return response instantly and run your function in background.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you put the `user indication` to `header` not `body`. Then you can use `stream` to reach your requirements.

**NOTE:** Next code is base on `python2`, you can change `http server related` to `python3 related api` if you like.

**server.py:**

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import time

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    Page = "Main content here."
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(self.Page)))
        self.send_header("User-Information", "Fetching module X. Please wait")
        self.end_headers()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.wfile.write(self.Page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serverAddress = ('', 8080)
    server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(serverAddress, RequestHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

**client.py:**

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080', stream=True)
print(r.headers['User-Information'])
print(r.content)
```

Explain:

1. If use `stream`, the `header information` will still be fetched by client at once, so you can print it to user at once with `print(r.headers['User-Information'])`
2. But with `stream`, the `body information` will not transmit, it's be delayed until client use `r.content` to require it(`Response.iter_lines() or Response.iter_content()` also ok), so when you do `print(r.content)`, it will need `10 seconds` to see the main content as it cost `10s` in server code.

Output: (The first line will be shown to user at once, but the second line will be shown 10 seconds later)

> Fetching module X. Please wait
>
> Main content here.

Attach the [guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests) for your reference, hope it helpful.

Comment: Thanks. But, in my case, the client side is from browser. :( In that case, how can we get it ?

Comment: If direct call from html, I'm afraid not. If call from javascript, maybe `websocket`?